# How to get getServerSideProps results in my IndexPage?

Tags: javascript, fetch, next.js

I don't think the getServerSideProps gets run, I'm just starting out and got no clue how to fix this, tried for a few hours but still getting undefined from the IndexPage console.log(props.data)

```
export default function IndexPage(props) {
console.log(props.data.copyright);
    return (
        <>
         <div>{props.data.copyright}</div>
        </>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const res = await fetch(" https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY");
    const data = await res.json();
    return { props: { data } };
}
```

Edited: the code works perfectly on local machine and vercel deployment, but not on codesandbox.io where I originally started /headache

Comment: What is "still undefined"? What behaviour do you want? What does this code do instead?

Comment: Trying to first console log the props.data in the IndexPage, and getting undefined instead of an object containing the fetch result

Comment: I'm following this tutorial on youtube https://youtu.be/Xwchwt8TIpk?list=PLUBR53Dw-Ef_oTLzPB3G5CdLWnGOSsec3&t=367

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a React Hook, and then call the function inside of that. You can then store the response in a state instead

Try something like this:

```js
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch";
import React, {useEffect} from "react"

    const IndexPage = props => {
      console.log(props.data);
      if(!props.data){
       return <div>Waiting for data...</div>
      }
      return <div>main page</div>;
    };

    export async function getServerSideProps() {
      const { API_URL } = process.env;
      console.log("inside fetch");
      const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/movies`);

      const data = await res.json();

      return { props: { data } };
    }

    export default IndexPage;
```

Otherwise you can use the 
`getStaticProps`Then ou are ensured, that the data is there, when the component fetches..

Comment: Any idea why, or what can I do to fix it ?

Comment: You are not calling the function. You have to use a React hook or similar... You can use the `useEffect`hook, inside your `IndexPage component`

Comment: Don't know much about `next.js`, but maybe you should use `getStaticProps`instead, looking at the documentation `You should use getServerSideProps only if you need to pre-render a page whose data must be fetched at request time.`

Comment: Then i think it is because, the data is not fetched yet perhaps?

Comment: try something like `if(!data){ return <div>loading</div>} console.log(data)`

Comment: can you [edit] your answer instead of adding complements in comments? ATM it's pretty much not an answer

Comment: if you look at the clip I was following ( pointed it to the exact minute) , https://youtu.be/Xwchwt8TIpk?list=PLUBR53Dw-Ef_oTLzPB3G5CdLWnGOSsec3&t=367

Comment: Everything is working fine without any extra hooks.

Comment: I even copy pasted the guy's code, still not working. Made afterwards a new project, with just the copy pasted code, nothing.

Comment: Indeed the code works on local machine but not on codesandbox.io. Why

Comment: It should work... If it does not work on codesanbox.io, maybe look into, if you have the correct setup there? Maybe missing dependency. Please consider accepting and upvoting answer :)

Comment: I will upvote the answer about importing useEffect, but the problem is not solved. Thanks alot for the time though! Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the page keeps showing Loading Data. Mind you, I'm a beginner :) I got to understand usestate hook, useeffect still waiting. I remember it can be used to load functionality on component life-cycle and / or whenever variables change. Never seen it in working beginner getserversideprops examples so far though, everyone keeps showing this simple code as I posted above.